# LDAP C SDK

Tags: c, sdk, ldap

I need to write a simple LDAP client in C.  The only binary distributions I found are old and also lack SSL tools needed to implement an SLDAP connection.  A complete and up to date distribution that I found is that of Mozilla however it is in source code format and I have not been able to compile it into binary form for windows.

I used the instructions described here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/LDAP_C_SDK.  I got up to the step where apparently I now need to use nsinstall but I don't know how this is done.  Does anyone know how nsinstall is to be used.?  Alternatively, does anyone know of an existing binary distribution of the LDAP C sdk for windows?  I also need the ssl libraries and associated tool for configuring the keystore.

thanks,
Mike

Comment: Having just battled LDAP :(, I would suggest finding a third party library!

Answer (score 1):

I used [The Google](http://www.google.com) a bit and ended up with this site that has Windows distributions of OpenLDAP: http://www.symas.net/portal/

OpenLDAP is heavily used on *NIX platforms, less commonly on Win32, but these folks seem to have done the heavy lifting for you.  Good luck!

Oh, and for docs and API reference, hit http://www.openldap.org